# Typescript throwing error on working code

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I'm implementing Typescript into an example project to practice the use of webpack, ES6, npm...

I have loaders 'awesome-typescript-loader', 'babel-loader' which are functioning fine as the code is being bundled and is running.

The problem is that when i test something like this -

```
document.getElementById('test-id').innerHTML = 'asdf';
```

I get an error in the browser console.

[image: Typescript browser console error]

However, the code *is* working, and the ID i am specifying is having that 'asdf' string injected.

I have tried alternate loader 'ts-loader', using `querySelector()` instead of `getElementById()`... also assigning the element to a variable, then trying to set the `.innerHTML`, but to no avail.

Comment: Is it possible the code runs twice? Once before the element is available?

Comment: Nailed it... the issue was that i'd installed html-webpack-plugin to handle script injection to the html, but hadn't removed the original hardcoded script link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution to this problem, as casraf guessed, was that the script was running twice, once before + once after the DOM had been loaded.

In this case i was using html-webpack-plugin to handle injecting script links, and still had a hardcoded copy in my index.html. It was solved by removing the hardcoded link.